# ¿Cómo contar mi listado para unas Pruebas Unitarias? Api Netcore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, pruebas-unitarias

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema, tengo una `api`, en la que le estoy haciendo unas pruebas unitarias, pero no consigo contar mi listado.

Pues no me reconoce `Count`

Codigo de mi `Controller`

```
public class Library2Controller : ControllerBase 
{
    private readonly ApiDbContext context;
    public Library2Controller(ApiDbContext context2)
    {
        this.context = context2;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Authors()
    {
        List<Author> lst = new List<Author>();
        lst = context.author.ToList();
        return  new JsonResult(lst);
    }
}
```

Código de mi  `UnitTest`

```
 [TestClass]
public class LibraryController_TestUnit : BDTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Library2Controller()
    {
        var nameBDD = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var context = ApiDbContext(nameBDD);

        context.author.Add(new Author() { id = 1, firstname = "juan", lastname = "perez", born = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-12-12"), death = null });
        context.SaveChanges();

        var context2 = ApiDbContext(nameBDD);
        
        var controller = new Library2Controller(context2);  
        var respuest = controller.Authors();


        var Author = new JsonResult(respuest).Value; //Coloco new JsonResult para obtener el value pero no lo trae directo
        Assert.AreEqual(1, Author.Count); // 
    }
}
```

Si coloco `Assert.AreEqual(1, Author.Count());` Me arroja lo de Abajo

> Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no
> accessible extension method 'Count'  accepting a first argument of
> type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?)

Otra cosa que no entiendo es que porque en esta linea `var Author = new JsonResult(respuest).Value;`

No me trae el `Value` directo, si no que me trae primero el tipo

Estoy iniciando con Pruebas Unitarias. Agradezco las sugerencias que puedan darme

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La propiedad Value del JsonResult te devuelve un object, por lo que no tienes acceso a la propiedad Count ya que no es una colección, para darle una solución rápida te recomiendo que hagas un parse, de esta manera:

```
        var authors = new JsonResult(respuest).Value;
        var list = (List<Author>) authors;
        Assert.AreEqual(1, list.Count);
```

Comment: fijaete al colocarlo como indicas, no me da error de sintaxis pero al ejecutarlo me indica que no se puede No se puede convertir el objeto del tipo 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult' al tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [ApiLibrary.Models.Author], eso en la linea donde utilizo la List

Comment: y es que como comente arriba a pesar de colocar var Author = new JsonResult(respuest).Value; sigue sin traerme el Value, es como si colocara var Author = new JsonResult(respuest)

Comment: He replicado tu código, y no tuve ningún problema al hacer el parse.

Comment: No logro entender entonces porque si aplico var Author = new JsonResult(respuest).Value; me trae authors = {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult}, cuando debe traerme es authors Count = 1

Answer (score 0):

Pude Solventar con lo siguiente

```
var controller = new Library2Controller(context);
var respuest = (JsonResult)controller.Authors();

var authors = (List<Author>)respuest.Value;
Assert.AreEqual(1, authors.Count);
```

lo que no me queda muy claro es la diferencia entre estas líneas

```
var respuest = (JsonResult)controller.Authors();
var respuest = new JsonResult(controller.Authors());
```

la segunda linea me explota y me da el error que comente arriba